# Counting number of nodes in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print the size of my binary search tree. However, what my code is doing now is printing what level each node is at. I feel as though I am putting my `count += 1` in the wrong place or perhaps it might be something else. I was wondering if someone could be an extra set of eyes for me and give me a hint on how I can fix this.

output:

```
3
3
2
3
3
2
1
```

expected output:

```
7
```

my code:

```
def BST_size(root, count = 0):
    if root is None:
        print "size -1 (Null value in root)"
    if root is not None:
        count += 1
        if root.left is not None:
            BST_size(root.left, count)
        if root.right is not None:
            BST_size(root.right, count)
    print count
```

Extra parts:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value


def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)

        if root.value < node.value:    # go to right
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)

r = Node(4)
# left
a = Node(2)
b = Node(1)
c = Node(3)
# right
d = Node(8)
e = Node(6)
f = Node(10)

BST_Insert(r, a)
BST_Insert(r, b)
BST_Insert(r, c)
BST_Insert(r, d)
BST_Insert(r, e)
BST_Insert(r, f)
```

Comment: `count` isn't mutable.

Comment: @Veedrac
Im still new to python but is count not mutable due to count = 0 I put as a function paramter?

Comment: "6 new answers; click to load" Did somebody say fizzbuzz?

Comment: As a side note, in all of your code, you're doing `if foo:` and then `if not foo:`. You don't need to do this; just use `else:`. Besides being easier to read, and not evaluating the same condition repeatedly, it also makes it impossible to screw up negating your condition and miss a middle case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

---

The easy way is to `return` the count from each recursive call, instead of just `print`ing it, and increment:

```
def BST_size(root):
    if root is None:
        return -1
    if root is not None:
        if root.left is not None:
            return 1 + BST_size(root.left)
        if root.right is not None:
            return 1 + BST_size(root.right)

def print_BST_size(root):
    size = BST_size(root)
    if size == -1:
        print "size -1 (Null value in root)"
    else:
        print "size", size
```

However, that still doesn't work, because you're only traversing the left side *or* the right side, not both. What you want is:

```
    count = -1
    if root is not None:
        if root.left is not None:
            count += BST_size(root.left)
        if root.right is not None:
            count += BST_size(root.right)
    return count
```

---

However, it looks like you're trying to use an accumulator, in tail-recursive style. There's really no point in doing this in Python, because Python doesn't optimize tail calls, but it's a useful skill to learn for other languages and for theoretical reasons, so…

The problem here is that you need the same value to be shared by all of the recursive calls, which means you need a mutable value. So, you can start with `[0]` instead of `0`, and do `count[0] += 1` instead of `count += 1`.

Or you can rearrange your code so that it doesn't use `count` mutably, and instead passes the updated count from one side down to the other.

---

Either way, you've got another problem with your code. Your recursive base case is that `root` is `None`. But you've also made it a special case, printing -1 instead of 0. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: SOrry, this might be a beginner questions but the function you provided me accepts only 1 paramter, however when you call the function again recursively in the if statement you gave it 2. Does the `count` argument get passed within the function? where the new `count` gets updated?

Comment: @Liondancer: Sorry, in the top-down version, there is no need for the `count` parameter, so I shouldn't have been passing it down. I'll edit the answer to fix that. Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

```
def BST_size(root, count = 0):
    if root is None:
        return count

    return BST_size(root.left, BST_size(root.right, count + 1))
```

Comment: Sorry, ended up posting the same answer as yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
def BST_size(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return BST_size(root.left) + BST_size(root.right) + 1

print "Size is: " + str(BST_size(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if root is not None:
        count = 1
        if root.left is not None:
            count += BST_size(root.left, count)
        if root.right is not None:
            count += BST_size(root.right, count)
return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short answer

You have to do tree treversal, where the function returns the number of nodes below + 1 (itself)

Pseudo code:

```
def counter(t):
  rCount = counter(t.right)
  lCount = counter(t.left)
  return 1 + rCount + lCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
def countNodes(root):
    count = 1
    if root is None:
        return -1
    if root is not None:
        if root.left is not None:
            count += countNodes(root.left)
        if root.right is not None:
            count +=  countNodes(root.right)
    return count
```

and invoke it like below:

```
print ("\nCount of Nodes :" + str(countNodes(root)))
```